# Is it possible to move (One folder to another) one text file at a time with (*.txt) using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have complied some data and I want to move one text file at one time to another folder using (*.txt). Is it possible?

I would like only that function with (*.txt) because it is complicated for me to use any other function and would suit my code best.

What I am trying to do is loop the Move.File function to 7 text files only in which one file only move at one time then the next file moves and so on. While moving one text file, another Naming function to extract the next text name. Hopefully that makes sense.

```
Dim FSO As Object
Dim SourceFileName As String, DestinFileName As String

k = 0
Do While k < 19
ActiveCell.Offset(-2, k).MergeArea.ClearContents
ActiveCell.Offset(-2, k).Value = Dir(FolderName & "*.txt*")
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
SourceFileName = "Y:\Engineering\*.txt"
DestinFileName = "Y:\Engineering\Completed\"
FSO.MoveFile Source:=SourceFileName, Destination:=DestinFileName
k = k + 3
Loop

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fnd As Variant
Dim rplc As Variant
fnd = ".txt"
rplc = ""
For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
sht.Cells.Replace what:=fnd, replacement:=rplc
Next sht

End Sub
```

What it does when I use this code it moves all the text files at once to that folder. So when I loop to name headings to text files it gives an error.

Comment: Moving them once is probably faster since loops repeat the same action many times which means more run time in this instance. Are you sure you don't want to modify the second part of the sub to work with the files after they have been moved?

Comment: No I wouldn't want to move them at once, because, firstly, I want to specify the amount of text files to be moved as there are multiple and I want to move recent files using dir(*.txt). Secondly, it would help me extract the headings off the closest files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your goal correctly then may try (tested to successfully perform according to my understanding of the goal)

```
Sub test()
Dim FSO As Object
Dim SourceFileName As String, DestinFileName As String
Dim FolderName As String
FolderName = "Y:\Engineering\"
FolderName = "C:\users\user\Desktop\Folder1\"    'modify to your requirement

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")

k = 0
SourceFileName = Dir(FolderName & "*.txt")
    Do While k < 19 And SourceFileName <> ""
    Debug.Print SourceFileName
    ActiveCell.Offset(-2, k).MergeArea.ClearContents
    ActiveCell.Offset(-2, k).Value = SourceFileName
    DestinFileName = FolderName & "Completed\" & SourceFileName
    SourceFileName = FolderName & SourceFileName
    FSO.MoveFile Source:=SourceFileName, Destination:=DestinFileName
    k = k + 3   ' Why K is being incremented by 3? It will only move seven files  
    SourceFileName = Dir
    Loop

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fnd As Variant
Dim rplc As Variant
fnd = ".txt"
rplc = ""
For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
sht.Cells.Replace what:=fnd, replacement:=rplc
Next sht
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ahmed! Works wonderfully! What part made only 7 text files to move? K= K + 3 because each heading have three merged cells on them, when k=18 they reach 7 headings